# Не работает атрибут android:icon в манифесте

Tags: java, android-studio, android-manifest

Ставлю атрибут `android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"`, но после запуска приложения выдает такую ошибку:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@icon value=(@mipmap/ic_launcher) from AndroidManifest.xml:13:9-43
is also present at [com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:13:9-45 value=(@drawable/ic_launcher).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:icon"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:9:5-23:19 to override.
```

Код в манифесте:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.studio.web173">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Main">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

В тег `<application>` нужно добавить `tools:replace="icon, label"`